# Why is my custom jQuery html tag adding break points that don't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Somehow I am getting additional break points when I'm trying to create a custom HTML tag in jQuery. Can anyone explain what I'm missing here?

**I have the following jQuery function:**

```js
$('address').each(function () {
        var link = "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent( $(this).text() ) + "' target='_blank'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>";
        $(this).html(link);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h6 class="centered">Copyright © <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> Company Name, LLC. All Rights Reserved <address>123 S Main St, Los Angeles, CA 90012</address><a href="tel:+11234567890">123-456-7890</a></h6>
```

**which produces the following footer:**

[image: Bad Footer]

**However, by simply adding the address manually like this:**

```html
    <h6 class="centered">Copyright © <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> Company Name, LLC. All Rights Reserved <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=123 S Main St, Los Angeles, CA 90012" target="_blank">123 S Main St, Los Angeles, CA 90012</a> | <a href="tel:+11234567890">123-456-7890</a></h6>
```

**I get the expected correctly formatted footer:**

[image: Good Footer]

Is this a hidden property of jQuery that I'm not aware of? I am fairly new to jQuery but I thought that the idea was a simple replacement of the DOM elements?

Comment: <br/> is just worked for the block tag.

Comment: the problem is with the `address` tag , i hope so

Comment: I tried to put it in a Snippet for you, but I couldn't replicate it, so I copied it to a fiddle for use in a comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ob19d1k9/

Comment: I added working snippets to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Its always good to use "inspect element"/"developer tools" first to know what's actually happening. because in your case you have no <br/> tag. But you assumed

Comment: Correct, there was no `<br />` tag, but I guess I didn't know a better way to explain the phenomena that was occurring. "Break point" is the only term I could think of to explain it. I've updated the title to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not replacing `<address>` tag in your jquery

use this

`$(this).replaceWith(link);`
instead of `$(this).html(link);`

If you use .html() it just adds inside the tag. But in your expected result you have no `<address>` tag. So What you want is `replaceWith`

Comment: Which is the preferable method? Using `replaceWith` or fixing the `<address>` tag to be `inline` instead of blocking?

Comment: if you use address tag only to add the google maps link then it is good to use replaceWith. It depends upon your usage. With the expected result you showed, I guess you won't need address tag and you need replace with.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek MVK !

Answer (score 2):

Your first example has the `address` tag in the footer, even after script execution. Your second example does not.

`address` is a block tag by default. Try setting `address { display: inline; }`.

---

The reason the `address` element is still in the document, is that `html` sets the *inner* HTML of the target node. If you want to replace the element with your custom content, you can use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) instead.

Comment: Well-spotted! So in fact, there as no `<br>` element at all.

Comment: I see... I thought I was creating the `<address>` tag when I created the jQuery function. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I was really close to adding this as the accepted answer. I think this answers the question of how to fix the `<address>` blocking problem, but doesn't exactly tell me why my jQuery function was wrong and how to fix it, which the accepted answer does. This was a question about jQuery, not CSS so I went with the jQuery answer. Thanks for explaining the `<address>` problem though @David Hedlund!